# Converting any date time from server time to user time (dealing with standard and daylight time)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am working on a web app using .NET MVC 3 and SQL server 2008 (r2).

Anyway, I have a date time object and I want to convert it to user time. It is fairly trivial to convert right now to user time; I have some java script that will get me the users offset from UTC. And I know my date times offset to UTC.

What I realized yesterday, is that my user's offsets will change, if they live in a pesky area of the world. And that would cause old dates and time to be wrong by some amount of time.

Now I know C# has some utilities to convert into a time zones time, but do they really handle all of the intricacies of daylights savings?

For example. If I have a time, 10-10-2001 8:00:00 how do I get that into pacific time? Or if i have 6-6-2004, how do i get that into pacific time?

Since the dates change for the roll overs, it is pretty complex, and I would like a general solution that does not require maintenance to set up date ranges for time zones.

I know this is a classic problem in CS, but I cannot find something that really answers my question 100%. From what I have seen: C# uses the current year's daylights savings dates to change every years date times. Which could cause some mistakes.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: At my previous job we used a calendar table which had a row for each date in each time zone that we supported, and the offset from UTC for that day. It was fairly easy to populate given daylight saving time rules, and fairly easy to update when President Bush changed the rules a few years ago. It costs you a lookup but the table is small and, if used often enough, is always going to be in memory anyway.

Comment: PS I described parts of this in a pro-calendar table article back in 2004: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

Comment: @AaronBertrand: "For that day" is tricky - how did you copy with transitions, where there are two offsets during the same day? (I prefer to do this client-side with an appropriate library, but hey...)

Comment: @JonSkeet what do you mean by two offsets for the same day? There is a row per time zone, per day of *every* year, not just a row per time zone for arbitrary Jan 1, Jan 2, etc. So for example November 1st 2006 would have a different offset than November 1st 2012.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I mean that on (say) October 28th 2012 in the UK, for the first two hours of the day the offset was +1, then it was +0. How can your table cope with that? Do you *also* store the time of day of any transitions?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, you should also store time of day that the change occurs, but that depends. Some models only store transactions that occur during business hours in each time zone, in which case whether the clock changed at 1 AM or 2 AM is irrelevant. In the article I wrote 8 years ago, no I did not have a column for that, but the system we implemented did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I know C# has some utilities to convert into a time zones time, but do they really handle all of the intricacies of daylights savings?

`TimeZoneInfo` does, yes<sup>1</sup>. (It's part of the .NET framework, not part of C# - C# is just the language you happen to be using.) However, I don't think that's what you really want to do.

Why are you storing the `DateTime` in the *server's* time zone anyway? It would be more sensible to store it in UTC, in most cases. Aside from anything else, if your server is in a time zone which observes daylight saving time, you will end up with ambiguity for one hour per year, when the clock goes back. (The same local time occurs twice.)

Once you've stored it as UTC, you should give it to your Javascript client as UTC too. While you say that you have "some java script that will get me the users offset from UTC" - that will depend on the exact instant in time. For example, as I'm in the UK, my offset is sometimes 0 and sometimes +1 hour. If you pass the UTC back to the client, that can work out the local time from that UTC time. Your server can't, unless you can get an *accurate* representation of the time zone from the client to the server, which is generally a tricky thing to do.

> From what I have seen: C# uses the current year's daylights savings dates to change every years date times.

Again, C# itself isn't relevant here. It's not clear which part of the .NET framework you mean - `TimeZone`? `TimeZoneInfo`? `DateTime`? `TimeZoneInfo` has historical data, but only if you're on an operating system version which supports it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, as far as you're likely to care. It doesn't have as much historical data as TZDB, and it has some very odd representations for Russia and Namibia, but it does generally have the idea of rules changing.

Comment: Thank you! You are right, .NET framwork not C# (n00b).

On a more serious note, we are working on moving to UTC but it is a coordinated batch of work and wont be done soon enough.

When you say "Pass to the client in UTC" then in the client side c#, i convert it using TimeZoneInfo via .Net?

Comment: @user1703963: In that case I'd convert to UTC on the server (you'll have to decide what to do with ambiguities) and then ship the UTC down to the client to convert into local time.

Comment: The good news is we do not celebrate daylight time where our server is.

Comment: @user1703963: That makes things considerably simpler :)

Comment: My trouble is using TimeZoneInfo... I played around with it once and have maybe a gap in my understanding of how it works. 

There is a method ConvertTimeFromUtc. Which takes a utc date time and a time zone. 

But how do i determine if the user was in standard or daylights time at the time I am trying to convert? That is where i get confused.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc.aspx

Comment: @user1703963: As I said, the server shouldn't need to get involved in the *user's* time zone at all. Just give the client back the UTC value, and make the client pass the UTC value to start with if you ever get information from them.

Comment: Hmmm i have a dramatic gap in my understanding of the web unfortunately. 

So if my client side has UTC. How do i show it to them localized.

Comment: @user1703963: That's a matter for a Javascript question, really - but you may well find there are *several* topics available on the web. Creating the `Date` object is very easy - you just give it "milliseconds since January 1st 1970 UTC". I don't know about formatting.

Comment: So... i would prefer to do it on the server side. Less code refactoring for at least my initial attempt. 

If I did know what timezone they were in. How do I signal timezone info to handle the awkward Daylight vs standard problem?

I am extremely grateful for your help on a side note.

Comment: @user1703963: No, you definitely *don't* want to do it on the server side. Getting the actual client time zone out of Javascript is a pain in the neck, as far as I'm aware. You can get the offset from UTC at any particular point in time, but that's doing the very transformation that you want in the server. You don't need to tell `TimeZoneInfo` to handle daylight saving transitions - it just does it. But as I've said, I don't think you want to use it here.

Comment: see my answe below with details, but basically I also recommend not to deal with time zones in server side. Simply use UTC format always in server side and when transferring dates between client and server.

Comment: @realavaloro: Well that's what I was suggesting here too ("It would be more sensible to store it in UTC, in most cases" and "Once you've stored it as UTC, you should give it to your Javascript client as UTC too.") However, I think the "always" in your own answer is too strong. Will add details in a comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following rules to be the best solution:

1. At server-side use UTC. No need to deal with Time Zones at all. That means that if you store dates in database, use UTC dates, if you generate dates in server side use generally UTC (e.g: `var nowDate =DateTime.UtcNow`). **The server dates should be location agnostic** and that way there is no confusion.
2. At client-side use UTC as well when dealing with raw data, but display the dates in the UI converted to the browser's local time (which will be whatever time is configured in the operating system). 
   **The good news is that this is already a built in capability in browsers**! we just need to make it easier for them to handle it.
   This means that if we have a javascript client code POSTing/PUTing/PATCHing data to a server and GETting data from the server using JSON, **the JSON should use the ISO 8601 (natively supported) in UTC (ended in Z)** as if you were doing:

   ```
   var dateNow = new Date(); //Wed May 11 2016 13:06:21 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
   var dateNowIso = dateNow.toISOString(); //"2016-05-11T01:06:21.147Z"
   ```

And then, simply rely on the browser capability to convert automatically any UTC date to the current local time and vice versa. The browser's javascript engine will be able to display in the UI the correct local time as long as the format is a `Date` object.

**NOTE on how to implement it for a .NET server & Javascript client scenario**: For example, I am using AngularJS (with restangular) in my client javascript code and MVC 6 (ASP.NET Core 1.0) in server side.

The JSON that comes from the server might contain date properties, but in JSON the type is a string such as:

```
{
  "myDateField":"2016-05-11T05:00:00Z"
}
```

In order to rely on the browser's capability to handle properly UTC times and convert them to local browser's time I need to parse this UTC date string into a real javascript Date object, so I use a regular expression to match any text value that looks like a UTC date in ISO 8601 format (in my case this code is in a restangular response interceptor but it could be anywhere):

```
const regexIso8601 = /((((\d{4})(-((0[1-9])|(1[012])))(-((0[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01]))))(T((([01]\d)|(2[0123]))((:([012345]\d))((:([012345]\d))(\.(\d+))?)?)?)(Z|([\+\-](([01]\d)|(2[0123]))(:([012345]\d))?)))?)|(((\d{4})((0[1-9])|(1[012]))((0[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01])))(T((([01]\d)|(2[0123]))(([012345]\d)(([012345]\d)(\d+)?)?)?)(Z|([\+\-](([01]\d)|(2[0123]))([012345]\d)?)))?))/;

function convertDateStringsToDates(input: any): void {
    // Ignore things that aren't objects.
    if (typeof input !== "object") {
        return input;
    }

    for (var key in input) {
        if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            continue;
        }

        let value = input[key];
        let match: RegExpMatchArray;
        // Check for string properties which look like dates.
        if (angular.isArray(value)) {
            angular.forEach(value, (val, key) => {
                convertDateStringsToDates(val);
            });
        } else if (angular.isString(value) && (match = value.match(regexIso8601))) {
            let milliseconds = Date.parse(match[0]);
            if (!isNaN(milliseconds)) {
                input[key] = new Date(milliseconds);
            }
        } else if (angular.isObject("object")) {
            // Recurse into object
            convertDateStringsToDates(value);
        }
    }
}
```

That way I can use my javascript object with proper Date objects.

In the server side (either MVC6 or WebAPI2..) I have an instruction to tell my JSON parser to ALWAYS use UTC formats when parsing Dates, otherwise it wouldn't add the Z character at the end, which is very important. Example for MVC6:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opt => {
  // json dates always in javascript date format with UTC e.g: "2014-01-01T23:28:56.782Z"
  opts.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
});
```

Inspired by [this article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates)
UPDATE: There are scenarios where it might be interesting to store data in local time as stated in the comments below.

Comment: The "always" is too strong here. There can be good reasons to store local date/time values. For example, if they're far in the future and the time zone rules may change, the local time is usually what would stay fixed. Likewise, for recurrent events, it's the *local* time of day that usually stays fixed, not UTC. Additionally, if you want to display times in a *different* time zone on the client (e.g. "I'm in UK, when will my meeting be for my Mountain View colleagues?" then doing that on the server ensures consistency (doesn't rely on browser time zone data being up to date).

Comment: yes, you have valid points there. I am removing the "always" from my answer

Comment: _"The good news is that this is already a built in capability in browsers!"_ No, that's the terrible news. I have a page where users are _expected_ to enter times in UTC. The browser just insists that's local to whatever locale I'm using and then shifts it by the local timezone offset before sending it to the server!