# what is the correct way to send json datatime to asp.net action for model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, datetime

What is the right way to send json datetime to asp.net mvc action so that Model can be bound to Json datatime?

I am using ajax to submit form to specific controller action and I am sending a lots of data, including MyDate (that is string, it contains data in the format dd-mm-yyyy, but it is not formatted using any specific dateformat like UTC, this date on client side is made from string concatenation and a result is string in the following format):

```
MyDate":"28-11-2013"
```

The Controller Action `public JsonResult Save(MyModel m)` receives data and converts json data to model `m` data, however, there is a problem with date field. The datefield in the model is defined like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "My date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd-MM-yyyy}")] 
    public Nullable<DateTime> MyDate { get; set; }
```

If json sends `05-11-2013`, then "month" and "date" parts of DateTime are mixed (05 should be date and 11 should be month, but it is vice-versa in the model `m`). If I send `28-11-2012`, then `DateTime` is set to `null` (because it is treated as incorrect date).

What is the right way to do this?

EDIT: I believe that the problem is related to Culture.

Comment: When you say "but it is not formatted using any specific dateformat" does that mean you have some written as mm-dd-yyyy and some as dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: I meant that it is not created as new Date or something like this. It is created from string concatenations and has format dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Take a look here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx  It would also be helpful if you posted your deserialization/parsing method.

Comment: Take a look here: http://blog.degree.no/2012/10/converting-json-date-string-to-javascript-date-object/

Comment: I do not have deserialization/parsing method, it is done automatically by Asp.net mvc model binding I guess. I am not familar with this yet.

Comment: Look at my answer here on what's the best way to handle dates in server side and client side considering time offsets and daylight saving changes, etc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37151569/2948212

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* use `yyyy-MM-dd` format.  It is defined by standards ([ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601)), and will not be misinterpreted.

[Obligitory XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1179/):

[image: KXCD ISO8601]

Comment: What if user needs another format? For example, there is input on the form where user enters his date and afterwards the form is serialized? Should I change the date format before serialization??

Comment: Always send ISO over the wire.  If you want to use a different format with your *user*, that's fine.  Do that in JavaScript.  Libraries like [moments.js](http://momentjs.com) can make that part easy.